# rails : Get/Set checkbox value in HTML5 fields dynamically from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, checkbox, data-binding

I have a Text field which contains HTML5 set by an HTML5 editor (CKEditor). Inside this text field and with the editor, I position and name some checkboxes like

```html
<div style="margin-left: 40px;"><input type="checkbox" name="CODE1" value="CODE1Value"> Contact authorized.</div>

<div style="margin-left: 40px;"><input type="checkbox" name="CODE2" value="CODE2Value"> Send email authorized </div>
```

which appear through a `<%= raw(@s)%>` in my view

Now, my question and my challenge is how I could databind (set/get) the checkboxes values (checked or unchecked) from/to a model in rails (eg: ["CODE1", false] ["CODE2, true]).

Thanks for any help or advice.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correct, you're trying to bind the two HTML checkboxes to the two attributes called 'CODE1' and 'CODE2' of a Rails model. 
IF this is the case, the Rails 'form' will take care of it all, once you have the 'form' acting on the right model. Here's a form wrapping on a model called User:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Contact authorized" %> <br />
    <%= f.check_box :CODE1 %> <br />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Send email authorized" %> <br />
    <%= f.check_box :CODE2 %> <br />
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks very much @G_89 for your help and reply. However, I did not explain the context clearly enough. Let's start with your example with model User, I have relationship has_many :authorizations (and Authorization belongs_to :user). The Authorization has a 'key' which identifies logically the checkbox (eg : "CODE1", "CODE2") and a boolean 'agree' which is set to true when the checkbox is checked and false if not. Then, based on the logical key 'key', and the value of the checkbox, I should set the data in Authorization correctly. Thanks

Comment: @P.Bra no worries! If those check boxes represent authorizations, and you would desire to set the authorization data in the context of a given user, then wrapping the authorization fields inside the User form using:
 <%= f.fields_for(:authorizations) %>
If you decide to move this way, then you would also need to declare accepts_nested_attributes_for :authorizations in User model, that strongly binds the two models and allow data for the associated model to be saved as the User object gets created/updated